# Focus cursor to a submit button

Tags: javascript, html

I have a standard form for a user login.

When I input the username and password, then press enter it gives the search result. The search text box is in the same page.

I want to set the focus on the submit button. The enter key issue only exists in IE? What can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: How is your document structured?

Comment: you can use the tabindex property! i guess it will work

Comment: What server-side framework are you using? Depending on what you're using, there are abstractions built into some frameworks that solve the problem you're having.

Answer (score 0):

You can focus anything with the focus() javascript method. This has nothing to do with PHP.

```
document.getElementById('ID_Name_Of_Your_Button').focus();
```

Comment: It is an answer to this question, but it is not a solution of the described problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Submit button must be defined **in the same form tag** as the other form elements. And submit will be fired on what form you are focused while pressing [enter].

You **don't need to focus** any submit buttons in your case.

And the document content is needed for the more exact answer of course.